# Include/exclude Input formatting by its type

Tags: css

The following css would make all inputs red inside a `div class="field_error"`

```
div.field_error input{  
    color: red;
    border: 2px solid #FF0000; 
}
```

Is it possible to say

case 1) exclude type=button ?
case 2) only apply type=text ?

How can I do these two cases?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Case 1**:
You can use the CSS3 :not() tag to exclude the inputs of the type button:

```
div.field_error input:not([type=button]) {  
    color: red;
    border: 2px solid #FF0000; 
}
```

**Case 2**:
This only selects the text inputs and colors them red:

```
div.field_error input[type=text] {  
    color: red;
    border: 2px solid #FF0000; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, using an attribute selector:

```
div.field_error input[type=text] {  
    color: red;
    border: 2px solid #FF0000; 
}
```

Notice the `type=text` filter.

In this case you dont need to explicitly exclude `type=button` since you only care about matching `type=text`